# How can I do command substitution in a .desktop file?

Tags: command-line, bash, launcher, .desktop, sh

Can I do bash-like command substitution in a .desktop launcher? For example, something analogous to this:

```
Exec=/some/prog --arg "$(zenity --entry)"
```

By that I mean "run this command and place its stdout in the containing command line, then execute that".

Is there a way to do it without making a separate bash script file?
I found [this hack](https://askubuntu.com/a/1147162/871240) (running `bash -c '...'`) that might work, but maybe there's a proper way to do it, like some .desktop special syntax?

**EDIT**: I just found out that the $(...) works as normal inside the .desktop file ... almost.

I still have the problem of making a failure (nonzero exit code) in the substitution command abort the enclosing command. How can I do that? I tried assingnig a variable like:

```
Exec= resp="$(zenity --entry)" && /some/prog --arg $resp
```

But it didn't work, because instead of aborting, it tries to execute the "&&" as a command when the inner command fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up having to use bash -c.

This is the way to properly handle command substitution with fail support, while passing the files in `%F` correctly. I have to expand `%F` outside the `'...'` quotes and pass the files as arguments, then expand them again with `"$@"` inside the single quotes, otherwise I can't properly handle multiple files with spaces on each path.

```
Exec= bash -c 'r=$(zenity --entry) && /some/prog --arg "$r" "$@"' "$0" %F
```

Comment: The reason for that is *substitution* is a shell function and `$0` also, secondly, a variable assignment does not produce an exit status, `&&` will not have any effect.

Comment: Yeah, `r=$(...) && etc` works on bash, but not on .desktop files.